# How to delay/slow down UIScrollView panning speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview with which I can zoom in and out, and pan around. However, I would like to give the ScrollView a floaty feel, where moving your finger from the left to the right of the screen makes the UIScrollView pan in a way where it gradually speeds up at the start, and gradually slows down at the end.

Nothing overly dramatic or disorienting, but to give a nice weightless feel to the UIScrollView. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about this?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, UIScrollView has **decelerationRate** property, with two predefined constants **UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast** and **UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal** values.

But if you want to slow deceleration rate, you may want to use custom floating-point value, something like:

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = 0.4;
```

Just try to experiment with this value and find what fits best for you.

Comment: This works great for deceleration, thanks! Though I was also hoping for a form of accelerationRate changer, if there are any known ways to do this.

Comment: There is no easy ways to do this. You can investigate possibility of modifying standard pan gesture recognizer in UIScrollView, and try to control it's offset by receiving gestures from that recognizer. Or add another UIPanGestureRecognizer to scroll view and use it instead. Anyway it's much complex matter then just modifying deceleration rate.

Comment: All right, thank you for the help with the first point anyway :) I'm accepting this as the answer due to float having more range of use than preset values as is the case in the answer below.

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options available,

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

If It can help you!